# How can I define a list field in django rest framework?

Tags: django, json, list, field, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have a class

```
class Tags(object):

    tags = []

    def __init__(self, tags):
        self.tags = tags
```

and a custom list field

```
class TagsField(serializers.WritableField):
    """
    Returns a list of tags, or serializes a list of tags
    """
```

I am not too sure where to go from here. How can I make sure that a blog post serializer defined as

```
class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    post = CharField()
    tags = TagsField
```

would give me a json object similar to

```
{
    "post": "Here is my blog post about python",
    "tags": ["python", "django", "rest"]
}
```

Comment: Docs on creating custom fields are here: http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields.html#customfields

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to deal with *arrays* for a non ORM-based object is to override the `to_native` and `from_native` methods. In your case:

```py
class TagsField(serializers.WritableField):

    def from_native(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, list):
            return Tags(data)
        else:
            msg = self.error_messages['invalid']
            raise ValidationError(msg)

    def to_native(self, obj):
        return obj.tags
```

If you had an ORM-based object you would like to look at the `SlugRelatedField` with the `many = True` attribute.

---

From Django Rest Framework version 3.0 you can also use ListField
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield

Comment: Is it working now? `from_native` is given `data[field]`, which is not list, but its last value. (Django 1.6, rest-framemork 2.4.3)

Comment: WritableField may not work with latest version of drf. Try serializers.Field

Answer (score 50):

There is also the ListField in django rest framework, see http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#listfield

wtih the examples:

```
scores = serializers.ListField(
    child=serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=100)
)
```

and (other notation):

```
class StringListField(serializers.ListField):
    child = serializers.CharField()
```

this seems simpler (maybe this class is added later than the accepted anwser, but seems good to add this option anyway)

By the way, it's added since djang rest framework 3.0: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/